# Hibernate is not downloaded in IntelliJ 11 IDEA

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

From what I have read Hibernate should have been downloaded to the lib folder when i select the facet, however nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong or do I have to download the Hibernate libs myself?

I am having the latest IntelliJ IDEA 11 Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine here (right click on the project root, **Add Framework Support**, Hibernate:

[image: hibernate]

[image: downloaded]

Double check your proxy settings. Also your provider may block some URLs or there is some other problem (check [idea.log](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) for exceptions).

See if you can reproduce it in the current [IDEA 11.1 EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP).