# Hibernate activation on IntelliJ

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm a recent IntelliJ Idea user and I can't figure out how to enable Hibernate. Hibernate does'nt appear in the "Add framework support" menu (actually the only technology I can select is Groovy) when I right click on my project.

I've read a similar message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673336/hibernate-is-not-downloaded-in-intellij-11-idea). I checked my proxy settings, which seem ok.

I also read the idea.log file, which contains several exceptions, however I couldn't conclude anything. Am I missing something obvious ? Thank you for your help.

Here are some exceptions from the idea.log file :

```
2013-06-27 13:59:28,897 [ 148537]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms 
2013-06-27 14:33:18,012 [2177652]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Creating VFS corruption marker; Trace=
java.lang.Exception
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.createBrokenMarkerFile(FSRecords.java:160)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.access$2100(FSRecords.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.invalidateCaches(FSRecords.java:1413)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.InvalidateCachesAction.actionPerformed(InvalidateCachesAction.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:259)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:892)


2013-06-27 17:00:00,750 [8794994]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2013-06-27 17:00:00,753 [8794997]  ERROR -       #com.intellij.util.Alarm - java.lang.InterruptedException 
com.intellij.openapi.application.RuntimeInterruptedException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:937)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeManagerImpl.filePathsDirty(VcsDirtyScopeManagerImpl.java:161)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener$FileAndDirsCollector.markDirty(VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener$FileAndDirsCollector.access$300(VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener$1.run(VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.ZipperUpdater$1.run(ZipperUpdater.java:64)


2013-06-27 17:00:01,086 [8795330]  ERROR -       #com.intellij.util.Alarm - IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4  Build #IC-129.713 
2013-06-27 17:00:01,086 [8795330]  ERROR -       #com.intellij.util.Alarm - JDK: 1.7.0_10 
2013-06-27 17:00:01,086 [8795330]  ERROR -       #com.intellij.util.Alarm - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
2013-06-27 17:00:01,087 [8795331]  ERROR -       #com.intellij.util.Alarm - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2013-06-27 17:00:01,087 [8795331]  ERROR -       #com.intellij.util.Alarm - OS: Windows 7 
2013-06-27 17:00:01,087 [8795331]  ERROR -       #com.intellij.util.Alarm - Original exception:  
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:996)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:776)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:934)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeManagerImpl.filePathsDirty(VcsDirtyScopeManagerImpl.java:161)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener$FileAndDirsCollector.markDirty(VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener$FileAndDirsCollector.access$300(VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener$1.run(VcsDirtyScopeVfsListener.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.ZipperUpdater$1.run(ZipperUpdater.java:64)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the log file, it seems that you have the community edition of IntelliJ. However, for support for Hibernate and similar frameworks you need the Ultimate edition.

You can compare the features of both editions [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/index.html).